# import pyttsx works in python 2.7, but not in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

**Question**: why is python3 unable to find the engine module when importing pyttsx?

**Details**:

I'm doing this on a raspberry pi with Raspbian Wheezy

Under python 2.7, the following works:

```
>>> import pyttsx
```

Under python3, the following happens:

```
>>> import pyttsx
Traceback (etc...)
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1-py3.2.egg/pyttsx/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: No module named engine
```

I've installed and used sudo pip install pyttsx

I've imported sys

sys.path contains this...

```
>>> print (sys.path) 
['','/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/setuptools-5.4.1-py3.2.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1-py3.2.egg', '/usr/lib/python3.2','usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload','/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages','/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

ls /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages results in...

```
easy-install.pth pyttsx-1.1-py3.2.egg setuptools-5.4.1-py3.2.egg setuptools.pth
```

unzip -t /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1-py3.2.egg shows....

```
pyttsx/__init__.py  OK
pyttsx/voice.py   OK
pyttsx/engine.py  OK
(etc...)
No errors detected in compressed data of pyttsx-1.1-py3.2.egg
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the library:

## pyttsx3

This python3 compatible version is now packaged in pypi and works pretty well for both python2 and python3 and as far as i have tested , it didn't give any error.

just use :

`pip install pyttsx3`

Usage :

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I am talking now ");
engine.setProperty('rate',100)  
engine.runAndWait();
```

Answer (score 8):

I attempted to install pyttsx on Python 3.4 (on Windows). Here's what I discovered:

The [pyttsx found on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx) was developed by [Peter Parente on GitHub](https://github.com/parente/pyttsx).

Parente has abandoned further development, and never ported it to Python 3. I cannot even get his version to install on Python 3. I am not sure how you managed this.

A user called [James Percent forked it](https://github.com/jpercent/pyttsx/) and made a fairly minimal attempt to make it Python 3 compatible.

I found that attempt didn't go far enough, because - while I could install it and even `import pyttsx` successfully, when I tried to call `pyttsx.init()` it would do a dynamic import of a driver, and fail with an import error.

I made a [further fork to fix that](https://github.com/Julian-O/pyttsx), which I will submit to James Percent. With those changes in place, I am able to run @Khanrad's test script.

Comment: James Percent has merged my pull request. I recommend using his fork, as it is more likely to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 Try this:

**`pip install pyttsx3`**

if it gives an error of engine like "engine is not found" then try to install this.

**`pip install python-engineio`**

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do...

In python 3, you have to call engine:

```
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say("What you want to say")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Can you confirm you have seen pyttsx work in Python 3, or is this hypothetical?

Comment: @oddthinking said it wasn't available. At the time yes, it was hypothetical