# pyttsx: No module named 'engine'

Tags: text-to-speech, python-3.4, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to install TTS package by using [this](http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html). Everything was okay until I tried to execute the following command:

```
import pyttsx
```

I got back this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyttsx/__init__.py", line 18, in module <br>
    from engine import Engine<br>
ImportError: No module named 'engine'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import pyttsx works in python 2.7, but not in python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963638/import-pyttsx-works-in-python-2-7-but-not-in-python3)

Answer (score 35):

Guys there is an updated package compatible with Python3 :

#### pyttsx3

Works offline with no delay in the sound produced.

#### Installation:

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

---

Visit https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io for the full usage docs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Combining the advice from [Jacob Tsui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676424/jacob-tsui) and [Jokhongir Mamarasulov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4755644/jokhongir-mamarasulov) worked for me.  To summarize:

In **site_packages/pyttsx/init.py**, modify "from engine import Engine" to

```
from .engine import Engine
```

Then, in **site_packages/pyttsx/engine.py**,

1. Modify `import driver` to

   ```
   from . import driver
   ```
2. Modify `except Exception, e` to

   ```
   except Exception as e
   ```

And finally, in **site_packages/pyttsx/driver.py** modify `except Exception, e` to

```
except Exception as e
```

See the responses from the aforementioned authors for the rationale behind these changes.

Comment: There is a fork of this project for Python3, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695104/importerror-no-module-named-driver-in-pyttsx This project seems to parallel the changes made above. However, on Mac, there is bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614648/importerror-no-module-named-foundation after bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614648/importerror-no-module-named-foundation after bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637233/badprototypeerror-objective-c-expects-1-arguments-python-argument-has-2-argume, so I'm bailing on implementing pyttsx on Mac, for now.

Comment: there will be a problem.. whenever u installed on another PC. user has to modify `init.py` file. But `pip install pyttsx3` will do fine.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem, try using **pyttsx3** instead of **pyttsx**
First install *pyttsx3*

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

and change the

```
import pyttsx
```

for

```
import pyttsx3
```

After that you have to change  **engine import** (if you're using it in your main .py file). Use **engineio** instead. Install it

```
pip install python-engineio
```

then change **import engine** for **import engineio** and change your variables.

Here's an example

```
import pyttsx3
# import engineio #engineio module is not needed.

engineio = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engineio.getProperty('voices')
engineio.setProperty('rate', 130)    # Aquí puedes seleccionar la velocidad de la voz
engineio.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(text):
    engineio.say(text)
    engineio.runAndWait()

speak("What do you want me to say?")
while(1):
    phrase = input("--> ")
    if (phrase == "exit"):
        exit(0)
    speak(phrase)
    print(voices)
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 7):

For `Python3`, please install the latest version via **pip3 install pyttsx3** and call `import pyttsx3`.

Answer (score 5):

**I found out the solution.** Library was created in python2 language and there are not a lot of differences between those 2 versions, but exclusively in this case that occurs.

Move to your DP folder and change in **engine.py** *"except Exception **as** e"* instead of *"except Exception, e"*, line 67. Do the same in **drive.py**, line 105.

Because of files are secured try to execute, e. g.

> sudo nano engine.py (or drive.py)

I guess I helped everyone with that kind of problem. :)

Comment: This is not the solution, I did what you said and still same problem.

Comment: Same here.. This didn't solve the problem.. @GLHF what did you do? how to resolve this issue?

Comment: GLHF - I have the same problem? what did you do?

Answer (score 5):

Modify site_packages/pyttsx/**init**.py "from engine import Engine" to

```
from .engine import Engine
```

Modify site_packages/pyttsx/engine.py "import driver" to

```
from . import driver
```

Reason: The import statement "from engine import Engine" tells python to import Engine module from directory engine. In our case engine is not a directory, it's a python file, engine.py. So we need to tell python to import this engine module from current directory (".").

Answer (score 2):

I used this code after

```
pip install pywin32 pypiwin32 pyttsx3
```

and it worked perfectly for me

```
import os
import sys
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('hello world ')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
First Try this command:

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

and then don't use

```
import pyttsx
```

use this

```
import pyttsx3
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

[pyttsx: No module named 'engine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615235/pyttsx-no-module-named-engine/67670758#67670758)

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyttsx/__init__.py", line 18, in module <br>
    from engine import Engine<br>
ImportError: No module named 'engine'
```

If the above one is your error then try install **pyttsx3** instead of
**pyttsx.**
Before installing check your python version,  then download the version which is compatible to your python version.

Refer [this link](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/2.6/) to get the previous **versions of pyttsx3**

**REASON:**

The reason we get the above error is because of the pyttsx3 version

which is not supported by your python version. Even if you get the error then

**FOR pyttsx**

Modify the init.py file located in
C:\Users\YOUR USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site_packages\pyttsx\init.py

Change

```
from engine import Engine
```

to

```
from .engine import Engine
```

**pyttsx**

Modify the engine.py file located at C:\Users\YOUR USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site_packages\pyttsx\engine.py

Change

```
import driver
```

to

```
from . import driver
```

These are the two main solutions for the above error