# pyttsx and gTTS module errors

Tags: python-3.x, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, espeak, pyttsx

windows 10-64bit

I'm trying to use some text-to-speech tool to read text from lines of .txt document, something like this:

so with pyttsx:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('my voice')
engine.runAndWait()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1, in <module>
    import pyttsx
  File "/.../pyttsx/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from engine import Engine
ImportError: No module named 'engine'
```

now gTTS, available as  gtts_token, so how to use it? because this way module is unrecognizable:

```
import gtts
blabla = ("my voice")
tts = gtts.gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
tts.save("C:/rec.mp3")
```

or:

```
from gtts import gTTS
blabla = ("my voice")
tts = gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
tts.save("C:/rec.mp3")
```

error:

```
 import gtts
ImportError: No module named 'gtts'
```

also I'm want try to use espeak  but not sure how to install it, is it available with pip install or I have to install it some other way to try it:

```
import subprocess
text = '"my voice"'
subprocess.call('espeak '+text, shell=True)
```

or:

```
import os
os.system("espeak 'my voice'")
```

so I'm trying to find some solution, but everything I tried is not working here...

Comment: see [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions) and make sure you installed `gtts` to the same version of python you are using.

Comment: pyttsx does not seem to be designed for python 3, see [pyttsx: No module named 'engine'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615235/pyttsx-no-module-named-engine) but the answer there did not make it work for me.

Comment: to install `espeak` just go to the dowload section of the [sourceforge site](http://espeak.sourceforge.net) and once it is installed the code you provided should work but I'm not certain since I'm using a mac. good luck to you though!

Comment: 'hi thanks, with pyttsx nothing helps. with your help gtts works, takes text from txt file `blabla = (line[0])` but first creates mp3 file, then if I want listen, I must call this mp3, so it is good but in my case I want avoid any audio files, need just read from text file. is it possible somehow use google voice to read my text file? I have not tried yet espeak... well if I can use only gTTS now have problem with mp3 file which I described in detail here because now it is a another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347786/how-to-play-mp3-from-gtts

Answer (score 3):

for **python3** use

#### pyttsx3

Its a new library compatible with both python3 and python2. Unlike gTTS it doesn't need internet connection and there is no delay in the sound produced.

#### Install:

`pip install pyttsx3`

#### Usage :

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hi this is working ");
engine.setProperty('volume',0.9)
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using windows 10 and Python 2.7.

**For pyttsx:**

Below code is working fine for me. I did get `ImportError: No module named win32api` error for which I had to install win32api from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/)

After that I could play "my voice". Although the quality and fidelity of spoken sound was very low. `gtts` is much better in that regards.

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('my voice')
engine.runAndWait()
```

For the error you are getting, Can you look into your python folder and see if `engine.py` file is present?

For e.g. in my case, I've `pyttsx` modules installed at following location
`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx` and here is a list of files,

```
 Name
 ----
 drivers
 driver.py
 driver.pyc
 engine.py
 engine.pyc
 voice.py
 voice.pyc
 __init__.py
 __init__.pyc
```

Since import of `engine` is failing, I am wondering if you have `engine.py` file in the correct folder or present at all.

**For gtts:**

I tried playing sound with `winsound`, but it did not work. Using `pydub` I was able to play the `audio file`. But, since your requirement is not to use a file, this may be a moot point.

```
import gtts
import winsound
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

blabla = ("my voice")
tts = gtts.gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
tts.save("rec.mp3")
print "Playing sound .."
#winsound.PlaySound("rec.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("rec.mp3")
play(song)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I responded to that question as well, check my answer and see if that helps.

Comment: hello gTTS reported here https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/32 and actual error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176555/gtts-httperror-403-client-error-forbidden-for-url and with pyttsx I have no idea how to figure out, because seems like it is installed, but I can't find any directory by path you shown in other words inside the site-packages.

Comment: I've install it with **pip install pyttsx** and install process was successful, and with https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/ same I've tried different but got same message  "python version 3.5 required, which one is not found in directory". also I can't figure out with espeak, same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127139/how-to-install-espeak-for-python-3-5-on-windows-10 have no idea what to do next

Comment: I've `windows ` with `python 2.7` running `pyttsx` successfully. I downloaded and installed from `https://github.com/parente/pyttsx` . Try that see if it works. [ may want to uninstall previous versions]

Comment: hello, I use python 3.5 on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I'm using python2.7 on Ubuntu.

Try to replace "from engine import Engine" with "from .engine import Engine" in the **engine** module.It work for me!