# how to play mp3

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, vlc, pyglet, pydub

my problem starts here:

[pyttsx and gTTS module errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323564/pyttsx-and-gtts-module-errors)

gTTS works well, takes text from text file, but first creates mp3 file, then if I want listen, I must call this mp3, so it is good but it would be better if I can avoid any audio files, and get just read from text file. maybe somehow I can use google voice to read from text file..? anyway main question now is other

if I can use only gTTS what is the best way to play mp3 on Windows 10-64 bit, Python 3.5

ok with os:

```
import os
os.startfile("D:\my path/rec1.mp3")
```

it is good, but I don't want use default player, need something like simpleaudio for mp3...

with pygame I have installation problem and  not sure, how good is use it this way:

```
from pygame import mixer 

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('D:/my path/rec1.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

vlc just how to install it? with `easy_install vlc` I got error: `could not find suitable distribution for requirement.parse ('vlc')` and with `pip install vlc` error: `could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vlc (from versions: ) no matching distribution found for vlc`

```
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:/my path/rec1.mp3")
p.play()
p.stop()
```

with pyglet:

```
import pyglet

music=pyglet.media.load('D:/my path/rec1.mp3')
music.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

I got this error:

```
'AVbin is required to decode compressed media')
pyglet.media.riff.WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media
```

subprocess also uses default player:

```
import subprocess

sound_program = "path to player"
sound_file = "D:/my path/rec1.mp3"
subprocess.call([sound_program, sound_file])
```

with mp3play, not sure how to use it:

```
import mp3play

filename = (r'D:\my path/rec1.mp3')
clip = mp3play.load(filename)
clip.play()
```

I tried it this way:

```
  filename = ('D:\my path/rec1.mp3')
```

this way:

```
  filename = r'D:\my path/rec1.mp3'
```

In all cases I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/dt/PyCharm_project/0_ASK.py", line 18, in <module>
    import mp3play
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\mp3play\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .windows import AudioClip as _PlatformSpecificAudioClip
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\mp3play\windows.py", line 27
    print 'Error %s for "%s": %s' % (str(err), txt, buf)
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

ok so with pydub:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment 
from gtts import gTTS
import simpleaudio as sa

blabla = ('my voice')
tts = gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
tts.save("D:/my path/rec.mp3")

rec = AudioSegment.from_mp3("D:\my path\rec.mp3")
rec.export("rec.wav", format="wav")

#rec = AudioSegment.ffmpeg ("D:\my path\rec.mp3")
#rec.export("rec.wav", format="wav")

#rec = AudioSegment.converter ("D:\my path\rec.mp3")
#rec.export("rec.wav", format="wav")

wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('D:/my path/rec.wav'')
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```

Errors in the sequence first with `AudioSegment.from_mp3` :

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " D:/dt/PyCharm_project/0_ASK.py", line 9, in <module>
    rec = AudioSegment.from_mp3("D:\my path\rec.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 438, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 366, in from_file
    file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(file, 'rb', tempfile=False)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 59, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\my path\rec.mp3'
```

with `AudioSegment.ffmpeg` :

```
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/dt/PyCharm_project/0_ASK.py ", line 12, in <module>
    rec = AudioSegment.ffmpeg ("D:\my path\rec.mp3")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

with `AudioSegment.converter`:

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/dt/PyCharm_project/0_ASK.py", line 15, in <module>
    rec = AudioSegment.converter ("D:\my path\rec.mp3")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

not sure maybe webbrowser, but how to install it?

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("D:/my path/rec1.mp3")
```

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here. It works with [playsound 1.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.1) for me.

Install with :

```
$ pip install playsound
```

test with:

```
>>>from playsound import playsound
>>>playsound('/path/to/a/sound/file/you/want/to/play.mp3')
```

Comment: `playsound` seems to fail the moment the path contains non-ascii characters though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "subprocess".

```
from subprocess import call
from gtts import gTTS
import os
blabla = input('Type IN: ')
tts = gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
tts.save("test.mp3")
call(["vlc", "test.mp3"])
```

This program asks user to type in anything and it will say that trough vlc.
I use this on Linux but i don't now if it works on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> with pygame I have installation problem and not sure, how good is use it this way:

Can you provide more details about the **pygame** installation error?

I was able to use **PYGAME** with this code, where "hello.mp3" is a file in the same directory

```
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS(text='Hello', lang='en')

tts.save("hello.mp3")

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('hello.mp3')
mixer.music.play()

root.mainloop()
```

> vlc just how to install it?

I also used **VLC**. I have installed it with these commands:

```
sudo pip install python-vlc
```

And I got this error:

```
NameError: no function 'libvlc_new
```

So, I tryed the command:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

And it worked with this code:

```
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS(text='Hello', lang='en')
tts.save("hello.mp3")

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("hello.mp3")
p.play()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope It help You.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job and without the need for files:

```
def say(text, lang='en'):
""" Speak the provided text.
"""    
import pygame
from gtts import gTTS
import io
tts = gTTS(text=text, lang=lang, slow=False)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()  # this is needed for pygame.event.* and needs to be called after mixer.init() otherwise no sound is played 
with io.BytesIO() as f: # use a memory stream
    tts.write_to_fp(f)
    f.seek(0)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(f)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.USEREVENT)
    pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.USEREVENT)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.event.wait() # play() is asynchronous. This wait forces the speaking to be finished before closing f and returning
```

Comment: I'm getting problems with IO and playback speed. I recommend not using this method for gTTS

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for :

#### pyttsx3

Its an offline cross-platform TTS that's compatible with python3 and python2.

#### Install :

`pip install pyttsx3`

If u want an offline TTS for python unlike gTTS , pyttsx3 is your best choice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to all of the questions, but the issue you're having with pydub is that you don't have ffmpeg or avconv installed. There are instructions on the [pydub github](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#getting-ffmpeg-set-up):

> Windows:
>
> 1. Download and extract libav from Windows binaries provided here.
> 2. Add the libav /bin folder to your PATH envvar
> 3. pip install pydub

Answer (score 0):

`webbrowser` should be part of you standard python install.
Check if there is a  `webbrowser.py` under `C:\Your_Python_Folder\Lib`.

Below code works just fine for me as `webbrowser.py` is present  at above mentioned folder.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("rec.mp3")
```

Comment: maybe I'm not quite correctly understood for what this tool is of how to use it, and most likely this is the case, but when I do this

`import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("D:\folder\folder\folder\rec.mp3")`

simply opens a web page

Comment: If you are using windows,try double backslash insted of single. e.g. `webbrowser.open("D:\\folder\\folder\\folder\\rec.mp3")`

Comment: Good that it works. Yes , it launches a window. Other option is to use external libraries like `PyDub` , `PyMedia` , `PyGame` etc. Else you will have to write your own driver.

Answer (score 0):

install pyglet using  `python -m pip install pyglet`

Download installed here [Link to AVbin setup](http://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Download.html)  ( it's a must )

32/64 bit

```
import pyglet

song = pyglet.media.load('file.mp3')
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use playsound module

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound(file.mp3)
```

Boom that's it.it plays the audio right way works like charm

Comment: Please check other replies in the thread before you post. The same solution has already been provided for over half a year when you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows then this should do the job,

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('your_file.mp3',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Remember this package is only present in python for windows.

Answer (score 0):

If AVbin error occurs...

First download AVbin.exe and Install it
then Go to local disk C --> windows --> System32 --> search the Avbin.dll and copy that file
then paste that particular file in your root directory

Error will vanish

Answer (score -1):

```
    import os
    os.system("music.mp3")
```

Comment: This opens a window though, instead of just playing the file.