# Speech text-to-speech with python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech

is that possible somehow to use text to speech for python 3.5

```
import speech
import time

response = speech.input("Say something, please.")
speech.say("You said " + response)

def callback(phrase, listener):
    if phrase == "goodbye":
        listener.stoplistening()
    speech.say(phrase)

listener = speech.listenforanything(callback)
while listener.islistening():
    time.sleep(.5)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/project/prog_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\speech.py", line 157
    print prompt
               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I have problem with gTTS maybe some advice here:

[gTTS HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176555/gtts-httperror-403-client-error-forbidden-for-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Traceback shows that code from the installed `speech` module is causing the *Missing parentheses in call to `print`* error. This shows that the module has been written to work in Python 2 – but not Python 3.

The two alternatives are:

1. Find a Python 3 compatible package; this may [prove to be difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614059/how-to-make-python-speak)
2. Rewrite your code in Python 2.

Comment: hello again thank you for support 

maybe you have some advice, how to figure out with **espeak** installation here:

[espeak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127139/how-to-install-espeak-for-python-3-5-on-windows-10)

Comment: @Ai_ve I'm afraid not - though I intend to try out espeak in the near future. BTW, I noticed you haven't [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) any answers to your questions. In case you’re not already aware, accepting marks the question as *answered* and (with upvotes) is the way thanks are expressed on Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but in case someone stumbles on this might be useful. This converts text to speech but also threads it so that the process can continue without having to wait for python to stop talking. For Windows only due to needing win32com

```
import threading
import win32com
def talk(wordsToSay):

   def thread_speak(wordsToSay):
      import pythoncom
      pythoncom.CoInitialize()

      speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

      speaker.Speak(wordsToSay)

   talk_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_speak, args=[
                               wordsToSay], daemon=True)
   talk_thread.start()
```

Throughout my application i will then call talk and pass in the text i want it to say. for example

```
talk("Hello, my name is Josh")
input('Just waiting for this to stop talking before closing")
```