# Pyttsx text to speech - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'

Tags: python, pyttsx

I am using Python3.7 on Win10. I would like to use Pyttsx but it shows an error. Do you have any idea how to fix the issue?

Error:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "C:\Python37\myTest\test.py", line 2, in 
> >         import pyttsx
> >       File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx__init__.py", line 18, in 
> >         from engine import Engine
> >     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'

test.py:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Good morning.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

**init**.py:

```
from engine import Engine
```

engine.py:

```
class Engine(object):
def __init__(self, driverName=None, debug=False):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using pyttsx3 instead of pyttsx First install pyttsx3

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

and change the

```
import pyttsx
```

for

```
import pyttsx3
```

test.py:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Good morning.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: You refer this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615235/pyttsx-no-module-named-engine" to get more explanation.