# Why does pycharm not like 'engine'

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I am trying to create my own personal assistant through the following tutorial http://letsmakerobots.com/node/41226

I am struggling to understand why this code;

```
import pyttsx   # text-to-speech library
engine = pyttsx.init()   # initiates speech engine
engine.say('Hello World')   # loads text into engine
engine.runAndWait()   # THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT, runs the speech engine
```

is producing the following result;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/theo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/VAtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyttsx   # text-to-speech library
  File "C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from engine import Engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'
```

When run from the command line it produces the following;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'engine' is not defined
```

Now I can see from the output that it seems to think there is not a module called engine but I cant see why; I have followed the tutorial correctly.

Thank you all I was using the wrong versions of programs, after an hour of testing I have resolved with a working build.

Comment: it looks like `pyttsx` is not correctly installed rather than pycharm issue. Does it work from Python console?

Comment: Did you name your source code file `engine`?

Comment: Double checked pyttxs, it is. I tried it in the console and got this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'engine' is not defined

Comment: Not as far as I know Stephen.

Comment: do you use Python 3.6 ? Maybe this module is not ready for Python 3.6 yet.

Comment: I do, I'll try backdating.

Comment: Seems to be a known problem, google "No module named 'engine'" to find out about it.

Comment: on page is: `Required: BitVoicer - Speech Recognition (this is where the $5 comes in), Python 2.7, ...` Maybe it needs `Python 2.7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open python console (in a shell type python) and type `import pyttsx` if the result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyttsx
```

the module pyttsx is not installed correctly

see this [pyttsx: No module named 'engine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615235/pyttsx-no-module-named-engine) and this [import pyttsx works in python 2.7, but not in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963638/import-pyttsx-works-in-python-2-7-but-not-in-python3)