# Python error: No module named 'engine'

Tags: python, module, pyttsx

I am trying to use the SpeechRecognition STT module for an AI i am coding and i'm also using Pyttsx but i get this error.

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyttsx/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
 from engine import Engine
 ImportError: No module named 'engine'
```

Alot of people have tried to answer this problem, for all the people having this problem but the answers aren't explained or don't work!

Here's my code

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx

speech_engine = pyttsx.init('sapi5') # see     http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx.init
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

def speak(text):
    speech_engine.say(text)
    speech_engine.runAndWait()

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

def listen():
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        return recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio) 
        # or: return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
    except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
        print("Recog Error; {0}".format(e))

    return ""



speak("Say something!")
speak("I heard you say " + listen())
```

if someone can explain and fix my problem that would be helpful 
thank you!

Comment: did you check this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615235/pyttsx-no-module-named-engine ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963638/import-pyttsx-works-in-python-2-7-but-not-in-python3

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link. 
It has all the updates compatible with python 3.
https://github.com/jpercent/pyttsx

Comment: please add some content from the link

Comment: This is a Python3 port of pyttsx, which is a cross-platform Python wrapper for text-to-speech synthesis.                                             
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Greetings!')
engine.say('How are you today?')
engine.runAndWait()
See http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/ for documentation of the full API.